# Can I launch a new Windows EC2 instance from a detached EBS root volume of a previous terminated instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I believe the direct answer is no.  An indirect way according to AWS docs is

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-launch-snapshot.html

you can backup the root volume as a snapshot, then create an image from the snapshot, and launch a new instance from the image.... but only in linux according to the link, not in Windows as I want to do. See the part below in the link above.

"At this time, although you can create a Windows AMI from a snapshot, you can't launch an instance from the AMI."

This link https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=42437

says this method works:

- Create an EBS volume "X" from the snapshot that has your good system on it.
- Run a new instance "A" of the base AMI.  This creates a volume "Y" as the main disk of that instance.
- Stop instance "A".
- Detach volume "Y" from stopped instance "A".
- Attach the good volume "X" to stopped instance "A".
- Start instance "A".

The link is from 2010 though, so just wanted to see if it's still the best way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think steps would be like this,
if you have root volume

1. You have the root volume "X" , select it **volume "X"** and right
   click ->  go to **create snapshot** option
2. After creating the snapshot go to snapshot menu and **select that snapshot** -> **right click** -> and go to **create image** option
3. go to AMI menu -> select that AMI which you create from snapshot -> **right click** -> go to **Lunch** option

I hope it helps , Let me know is that working for you

Comment: It doesn't work because as mentioned in the OP, you can create a Windows AMI but you can't launch it under Amazon's current setup. Just to be sure, I tried it, and after clicking launch, the console says the instance is running, it fails the "instance status check" and you can't RDP in.

Comment: I was able to confirm though that the method at the bottom of the OP does work. I am new to EC2 though so I was hoping someone who has experience could let me know if there could be issues with that method.

Comment: Bobo I have a snapshot and I am able to lunch AMI. Are you paste your steps may be some thing is missing from my side or yours. Happy to help you ..

Comment: Ahh..I was creating a snapshot from the EBS volume and then creating an image from the snapshot. That route does not work. Creating an image right from the EBS-backed instance itself does work. Curiously though, when I launched a new instance from the image, it terminated the stopped instance the image was based on. I assume that's normal behavior, but why? I thought the two instances could coexist?

Comment: Bobo I don't Know what wrong with that . Can you send me email on 4344553@gmail.com